# unity 3d error CS0118

Tags: unity-game-engine

I get this error:

> Assets/initadmod.cs(25,2): error CS0118: `Admob' is a`namespace' but a `type' was expected`

Please copy this script to your MonoDevelop to see where is error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Admob;



namespace Admob {

namespace GoogleMobileAds {

public class initadmod : MonoBehaviour {
    public static initadmod instance;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        instance = this;
        Debug.Log("start unity demo-------------");
         initAdmob();
    }
    public string baner_Adr;
    public string fullbaner_Adr;

    public string baner_IOS ;
    public string fullbaner_IOS  ;

    Admob ad;



    //bool isAdmobInited = false;
    void initAdmob()
    {
        string adUnitIdbaner  ;
        string adUnitIdfull ;
        //  isAdmobInited = true;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
          adUnitIdbaner = "baner_Adr";
             adUnitIdfull = "fullbaner_Adr";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
              adUnitIdbaner = baner_Adr;
              adUnitIdfull = fullbaner_Adr;
#elif UNITY_5 || UNITY_IOS || UNITY_IPHONE
               adUnitIdbaner = baner_IOS;
               adUnitIdfull = fullbaner_IOS;
#else
                adUnitIdbaner = baner_Adr;
               adUnitIdfull = fullbaner_Adr;
#endif


        ad = Admob.Instance();
            ad.bannerEventHandler += onBannerEvent;
            ad.interstitialEventHandler += onInterstitialEvent;
            ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler += onRewardedVideoEvent;
            ad.nativeBannerEventHandler += onNativeBannerEvent;
            ad.initAdmob(adUnitIdbaner, adUnitIdfull);
            //   ad.setTesting(true);
            Debug.Log("admob inited -------------");

    }
    public bool ShowBanerOnPlay;
    public bool _ShowFullOnBackToMainMenu;
    public bool _ShowFullNowOnOpenGame;
    public int ShowFullOndie;

    /// <summary>
    ///  hiện baner nhỏ góc trên màn hình lúc chạy
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowBanerOnPlayGame()
    {
        if (ShowBanerOnPlay)
        {
            ShowBaner();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// hiện baner lúc chết
    /// sau Showfullondie số lần chết mới cho hiện
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowFullOnDie()
    {
        if (UImanager.uimanager.showbane >= ShowFullOndie-1)
        {
            showInterstitial();
            UImanager.uimanager.showbane = 0;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// hiện qc khi đến menu chính
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowFullOnBackToMainMenu()
    {
        if (_ShowFullOnBackToMainMenu)
        {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// hiện quảng cáo khi mới mở game ra khi hết mục dowload
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowFullNowOnOpenGame()
    {
        if (_ShowFullNowOnOpenGame)
        {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    }
    void showInterstitial()
    {
        if (ad.isInterstitialReady())
        {
            ad.showInterstitial();
        }
        else
        {
            ad.loadInterstitial();
        }
    }
     void ShowBaner()
    {
        Admob.Instance().showBannerRelative(AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.TOP_CENTER, 0);
    }

  public    void HideBaner()
    {
        Admob.Instance().removeBanner();
    }

    void onInterstitialEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onAdmobEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
        if (eventName == AdmobEvent.onAdLoaded)
        {
            Admob.Instance().showInterstitial();
        }
    }
    void onBannerEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onAdmobBannerEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    }
    void onRewardedVideoEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onRewardedVideoEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    }
    void onNativeBannerEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onAdmobNativeBannerEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    }




}

                }
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

On line 25 you are declaring

```
Admob ad;
```

but Admob is a namespace, not a class, so you need to add the class to your declaration, maybe something like (this is just an example)

```
Admob.GoogleMobileAds.initadmod ad;
```